# Download from SourceForge without using the browser

Tags: portable, sourceforge

I need to download Firefox as a [portable app](http://portableapps.com/) from [SourceForge](http://www.sourceforge.net/)., but I am using IE6 and the browser crashes before the download can finish.

I have found that [SourceForge no longer supports IE6](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/ticket/6312), so I am stuck in a catch 22 here. Is there any way of accessing SourceForge without using the web-browser?

(To clarify, normal download of the Firefox browser as a non portable app is not an option for me)

Comment: are you able to use svn? then this would be your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I clicked the link and clicked on Firefox, I followed the link and downloaded from SourceForge.

I have [uploaded it here](http://www.mediafire.com/?nymnmtxzy2h) so you have an alternate location.

If you are still having problems, please write in comments and I will put it on a ftp server for you and give you the commands you need to download without involving Internet Explorer at all.

Ivo said about wanting a guide, For Windows, the easiest thing to use is the FTP command, but it looks like SourceForge do not offer FTP access. If you are interested, if you ever want to get a file by command line FTP do the following:

(In all steps, I am using an example of : ftp:google.com/test/bla.exe)

1. Go to command prompt and navigate to the folder you want files to go in.
2. Type `FTP Servername.com` for example, `FTP google.com`
3. Authenticate, either type username/password, or anonymous twice.
4. Find the file you want, generally you can type `LS` or `DIR`, type `CD directory` to change directories. For example, `CD test`
5. Type `GET filename` so `get bla.exe`
6. Type `QUIT` when done.

Now, when you look, you should have the files you downloaded in the current folder.

There are other techniques involving programs such as Fetch or Curl, where you would just type the full path of the file and it will get it, however, I do not really want to recommend you download any extra programs.

Comment: +1 for being helpful, though I actually would like someone to explain how I could do this through the command line or something :P

Comment: well - I am not sure it is possible for the portable version as it appears to only be on sourceforge, and they do not offer FTP... obviously for Linux you can use curl/fetch etc, but there is no built in command to Windows for this, and I don't really want to recommend installing more software.... My main FTP server is all automated with a DB for clients - I do not want to mess around, I only have a "test" server that I can use, and I do not really want to upload there if I do not have to which is why I said I would if there is still problems (but bandwidth is slow etc.)

Answer (score 0):

theres always wget. or use 2get portable :)

Comment: And how do you get them, without using the browser, on Windows? ;)

Comment: I thought of that too...but as Gnoupi pointed out has Windows no such convenient 'features' nor applications built-in. ;)

Comment: They are PORTABLE APPS :) go to a library, download them install them on USB.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. How to use these?